# Background Process in REST (Jersey2)

Tags: java, rest, process, jersey-2.0

I have an REST-endpoint(A) that periodically sends data to an REST-endpoint (B) via POST.
I'm working on B. This endpoint has to subscribe at A and then show the latest data in a component (I would prefer a swing GUI).
The subscribtion should be triggered by the user. 
So I'm thinking of a way to start a background process for my REST service that holds the GUI-component for subscribtion and show the data.

But WebServices don't have an "entry-point" for starting services.How can I start processes that run while the stateless requests are beeing processed? 
What is the common way to design such problems/tasks?

Comment: Why would your REST service hold any GUI components? You could add your own [ServletContextListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) to start your background task.

Comment: It should hold a GUI component to visualize the incoming post request of a resource.
I'll try ServletContextListener, thanks.